# Stack Overflow Exception on Auto Properties

Tags: c#, exception, properties, stack, overflow

my application is throwing Stack Overflow exceptions on the startup on some auto properties and objects creation.

They were working without problems, I have not modified them.

Basically I have an abstract class "Rule" that implements an interface "IRule", those properties are from the interface. 
Then I have a child class that inherits from Rule, I get the exception on that child class.

Edit:

```
public class RuleA: Rule
{
    private RuleA_bestSettings;

    #region PROPERTIES

    public override Rule BestSettings { get { return _bestSettings; } set { _bestSettings = value as RuleA; } }


    #endregion

    public RuleA()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();

        _bestSettings = new RuleA();
    }



}
```

}

Now I'm getting the exception on the Initialize method when I instantiate the property

This happens when a new object with those properties is instanciated.

```
Si è verificata l'eccezione System.StackOverflowException
  HResult=0x800703E9
  Messaggio=Generata eccezione di tipo 'System.StackOverflowException'.
```

I can't figure it out, any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps your question is better if you add also the code where you use this property and where you get the exception

Comment: Can you post the exception and call stack? That property looks fine. It's something else.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the question.

Comment: I added the method where I get the exception

Comment: I have not more code about those properties, it's all there. I don't know how to share the entire source code.

Comment: where and how do you call `Initialize`?

Comment: That's the problem that can happen with virtual methods, common scenario is when non-virtual method is calling virtual method and overridden virtual method is calling that non-virtual method again. this will cause SO exception.

Comment: Sorry guys for the confusion, I've updated the question, I hope now it's clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Initialize` section, you are instantiating a new `RuleA`. This new `RuleA` will construct itself and in so doing it will call its own `Initialize` section and create a third `RuleA`. Which will create a fourth. And a fifth. And so on, until the stack fills up.

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but my guess is that instead of this

```
protected override void Initialize()
{
    base.Initialize();

    _bestSettings = new RuleA();
}
```

you meant to do this:

```
protected override void Initialize()
{
    base.Initialize();

    _bestSettings = this; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, should be this the problem..That is the last change I did on the class. Basically I need a new object of the same type RuleA as property. I made a mistake to instantiate it on the Initialize method that is called on the constructor. I have moved it on the another method and now it's working! Thanks so much to all for the help and sorry for the confusion.